# I get data in English when I send https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&mode=driving&language=iw

Tags: android-studio, duration

return me text in duration in English when I ask in Hebrew

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=metric&origins=31.923653790756987,35.04286816346929&destinations=31.905535,35.017173999999997&mode=driving&language=iw

Comment: Welcome, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.  We need more information like code and stack trace to be able to help you.

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that Hebrew text should be supported? If you ask for Spanish, French or Chinese, what do you get?